# Node.js 6.x async/await in required libs with Babel

Tags: babeljs, koa

For some reason I should use Node.js 6.x (actually 6.10.0) and I'm trying to run koa2 with Babel as described [here](https://github.com/koajs/koa#babel-setup). My code looks like this

```
const Koa = require('koa');
var app = new Koa();

// --- middlewares ---
async function a(){await 1} // okay here!
console.log(a());
const serve = require('koa-static');
app.use(serve('./web'));
app.use(require('koa-cookie').default());
app.use(require('koa-bodyparser')()); // fails here
```

And I'm getting error

```
D:\Project\node_modules\koa-bodyparser\index.js:72
  return async function bodyParser(ctx, next) {
               ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
```

Running node with `nodemon index.js --exec babel-node` on Windows
Works perfect on Node 7.x, but I need to use 6 unfortunately :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) are not yet supported in Node.js 6.x. They are ES2017 features and are only supported in Node 7.6+.

The Babel preset you're using is obviously not working - make sure you are using the correct babel preset (ES2017) as per the [instructions](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2017/) on the Babel site.